# How to create text on a tkinter canvas and change the text in the canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a game using tkinter, and need to change some of the text in a function. How do I initialize a text box and change the text in the text block?

I have tried to create text and then in a separate function I used `itemconfigure` to update it but I got an error.

```
self.player1_troops = self.canvas.create_text(80, 140,text='')
self.player2_troops = self.canvas.create_text(1210, 140,text='')
def changeValues(self, player1, player2):
     self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.player1_troops, player1.printTroops())
     self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.player2_troops, player2.printTroops())
```

I expected the text blocks value to change but instead I recieved and error about an unknown object.

Comment: You should post here the exact error that you are getting.

Comment: `itemconfigure` is used to change many different properties in object - and it doesn't know that you want to change property `text` - `itemconfigure(ID, text="...")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell `itemconfigure` which property to change. You should use it like this:

```
self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.player1_troops, text=player1.printTroops())
```

Notice the addition of `text=`.